# Jenkins run without build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have made a simple program that needs to be executed once in every hour. I've set in Jenkins to run every hour and run shell commands at post step of the build.

The thing is that it needs to build only when the code is changed on GIT. If nothing has changed, I'd just like to run the post steps without the new build.

Is there any way to take care of this? I just can't find any plugins to take care of this.

- git change -> build -> run post step.
- git not change -> build X -> run post step every hour

Thanks in advance.

**-edit-**

This simple program is currently running on my Jenkins every hour as below.

trigger(every hour) -> get code from Github -> build -> run post step(executing three shell commands)

But! I want to change to

trigger(every hour) -> <strike>get code from Github -> build -></strike> run post step(executing three shell commands)
+
trigger(when Github code changes) -> get code from Github -> build -> run post step(executing three shell commands)

Comment: Your question text and bulletted points are not in sync. Can you please check and ask again which one is correct?

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy Thank you for the comment. I've re-read my question few more times. But I think text and bulleted points are in sync. I've added some more text since my question may not be clear enough.

Comment: how did you configured to invoke a build upon code change? git hook?? calling build using url?

Comment: I've abused tools before, but Jenkins as a job scheduler makes me shudder.  It's either brilliant, madness, or both! :)

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy well, at Build Trigger under the configuration of this application, I've checked the checkbox for Schedule and set it to 'H * * * *'. Also, I've checked the checkbox for 'Build when a change is pushed to Github'.

Comment: If you want, you can [chat with my here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164540/jenkins-run-without-build). I will help you.

Comment: I can't chat due to lack of my points in stackoverflow. It looks like what Marcos suggested can be one of the solutions. I'll try that one. Thank you, SVMadhavaReddy for your kind consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you can set your job to build on a Git push to master (or whatever branch) using a Git hook while also keeping the hourly build and add a check in your code for the build cause. Something like (this is inside an execute shell step):

```
if [ $BUILD_CAUSE != 'TIMERTRIGGER' ]; then
  build your code
fi

execute 3 commands
```

That way builds triggered by the timer will skip the code build but manual or hook triggers will not.

If you are using pipeline you can use `currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses()[0].getShortDescription().contains('text identifying git trigger')` for similar results.

Edit: an alternative solution using the Conditional BuildStep plugin.

Add a Conditional Step (single) with the trigger as build cause SCM Trigger as the first step on the build and add a second build step to run the shell commands. See attached screenshot (in the image the Post build Actions tab is highlighted but this is done in the Build section).

[image]

Comment: I think you've understood what I'm trying to do. looks the solution needs to be input at the Build Trigger under configuration. But there is no option for this. I only have 8 options as follow.
1)Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built
2)Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)
3)Build after other projects are built
4)Build periodically
5)Build when a change is pushed to GitHub Help for feature: Build when a change is pushed to GitHub
6)GitHub Pull Request Builder 
7)Poll SCM Help for feature: Poll SCM
8)[BuildResultTrigger] - Monitor build results of other jobs

Comment: You need so select 4 Build periodically (set to hourly) and 5 Build when a change is pushed to GitHub.   

Set up your repository in the Source Code Management section and pick the master branch for your project (assuming that every commit there will trigger a new build).   

Then you add an Execute Shell build step with the code I posted above.

Are you using the Groovy pipeline DSL or freestyle jobs?

Comment: Thanks, @Marcos I've understood what you are trying to tell me. I kind of new to Jenkins, so I guess the answer to your question is freestyle job. I've already set 4 and 5 at the build trigger. I'm curious where I can put the Shell script. After Build Trigger tab. I have 1)Build Environment, 2)Pre Steps, 3)Build, 4)Post Steps, and so on. Currently, 1,2 is not used. On 3, it's set to build with pom.xml and On 4, I'm executing 3commands. I think I need to have a tab something like Build conditions between 2 and 3. But can't find any. Got any Ideas?(I don't have any execute shell in Build tab)

Comment: On 3 Build you can add a step called Conditional Step (single) and pick Run? Build Case SCM Trigger. This is going to be your build pom step. Then add another step to run the 3 commands, they are going to be executed every time. You might need to install the Conditional BuildStep plugin for it to show up. @RoyKim

Comment: I have perfectly understood what you are trying to do. I've checked Conditional BuildStep plug-in (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin). So bad the drop-down menu doesn't appear to me. under Conditions tells the reason. should I wait for the upgraded version of the plug-in? got any solutions?

Comment: That's weird. Have you restarted Jenkins after installing the plugin? I'll edit the post and add a screenshot. @RoyKim

Comment: No, I don't have the 'add build step' button under 'Build' tab. I'll check with my team about the jenkins again. I have definitely understood the solution. I think I can handle as the button appear. Thank you @Marcos, for all your help.